# How to split a video into individual encoded frames?

Tags: ffmpeg

Source video is H264 in an mp4 container, I'm trying to split it into individual encoded frames. I tried with the following command line:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -f image2 "%d.h264"
```

But that creates jpegs with the extension "h264", rather than actual H.264 frames.

Comment: I think you want to split a video into H264 I frames?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It turns out the correct command line is:

```
ffmpeg -i "inputfile" -f image2 -vcodec copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb "%d.h264"
```

Comment: How did you combine the frames back into a video?

Comment: I did not. The point was to feed the frames to a decoder for benchmarking purposes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as an "h264" image.  H264 is a standard for video compression, and contains many different iterations, profiles, and also proprietary implementations of h264 encoders and decoders.

If you are trying to convert an avi video into an image sequence, you will need to determine what image format you want the exports to be.  If you don't want to re-encode the media, you can use the `-f image2` argument to specify an uncompressed image format.  You can then save the outputs into something like a bmp, png, or tiff container.  Alternatively, you can compress the images into something like a .jpg container (which perhaps FFmpeg defaulted to in your original command because you didn't tell it an image container that it understood).

.... edit:  If for some reason you are trying to create a sequence of video files that only contain one frame each, it doesn't make any sense to compress them with h264.  H264 is a temporally based encoding method and would require more than one frame.  You could I guess make a sequence of uncompressed video files that only contain one frame each, but I can't imagine what the purpose for that would be when images would accomplish the same thing

Comment: I am not trying to create a sequence of video files, I'm trying to extract the payload of each H.264 frame and put that each in its own file. Yes an H.264 frame exists, that's what H.264 videos are made of.

Comment: Yes, an h.264 frame exists, but predictive and bidirectional frames within a GOP cannot stand alone independent from their reference frames.  In order to separate a predictive h264 frame from it's references, and save it into a new independent file, you would need to re-encode it (either by compressing, or by using an uncompressed codec that can first decode all the images within the GOP, grab the image that you need, and then save it into it's own file).
If you tried to grab the image without first decoding through the GOP and re encoding, you would result in an image with missing macroblocks

Comment: I know and don't care about any of that. I never said I intend to be able to view each frame independently, only to save it as a file.

Comment: Maybe it would be more helpful if you included a little more information about what your end goal is here. Do you intend to save a "partial" image, keep metadata, and store motion vectors independent from their references?  I don't think that is possible (at least not within FFmpeg)... If I'm way off track here, it may help If you can include a bit more information.

Comment: An H.264 video file is a sequence of H.264 frames. I intend to create a sequence of files each containing one of these frames. Anyway, I found my answer, see my answer above.

Comment: interesting, glad you figured it out. Sorry if I misunderstood your end goal - I thought you were trying to create a folder containing individually decodable frames.... I just tried your command on a file - interesting string of data.  It almost looks like a hex dump of each frame.  .. and pretty cool that FFmpeg can individually decode each i-frame within the folder, but can't understand what the P frames are!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would something like this be useful for? - would it be for streaming smaller packets of data and then recombining them on a foreign machine or something? -- I guess that wouldn't quite make sense because FFmpeg can handle streaming natively.  -- just curious!

Comment: I'm basically trying not to take a dependency on FFmpeg (or any other parser) in my application, all I need is for the video to be split into individual frames and the video won't change often. So I can just pre-generate the frames and not have to touch FFmpeg at all in code.